# Change Opacity of Style

Tags: openlayers, transparency-opacity

Is there any convenient way to change the opacity of a ol.style.Fill or ol.style.Stroke Object?

As far as I understand it, there are 2 ways to define a color with an opacity.

```
fill.color = [255,0,0,myOpcitay];
```

or

```
fill.color = 'rgba(255, 0,0,myOpacity)';
```

But what If I get a color attribute in hex format, like

```
var color = myStyle.getFill().getColor() // color #FF0000;
```

Do I really have to decompose the hex color definition in order to add the opacity? There must be a more user-friendly way to achieve this...

Comment: OpenLayers seems to return the same format which was used to set the style.  So if you need to change one component always use an array,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ol.color.asArray` method for that. Fourth element of array is then opacity:

```
var color = myStyle.getFill().getColor();
var colorArray = ol.color.asArray(color);
var opacity = colorArray[3];
```

**EDIT**: As Mike rightfully pointed out, above code is suitable only for reading opacity. Since `asArray()` method returns cached color, if we want to change color and use it independantly, copy of the color has to be created with `slice()` method (Mike's code):

```
var color = myStyle.getFill().getColor();
var colorArray = ol.color.asArray(color).slice();
colorArray[3] = 0.5;
myStyle.getFill().setColor(colorArray);
```

Comment: The API mentions the array is cached so be sure to clone it using slice otherwise you might change all red styles to semi transparent red.

`var colorArray = ol.color.asArray(color).slice();
colorArray[3] = 0.5;
myStyle.getFill().setColor(colorArray);`

Answer (score 1):

Would a 8-digit hex-code work?

See also:

- https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#hex-notation
- https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes

Have also a look at this page:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28033076/42659

Comment: dead link unfortunately

Comment: link should work now :)

Comment: still, it is a hassle to do math on a variable that might be 'red', '#FF0000', 'rgba(255,0,0,0)' or [255,0,0,0]

Comment: does this helps to ease the hassle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28033076/42659